# Is it possible to use multiple params in the itemLabel of a form:select/form:option

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using Spring.  I've got a JSP with a form:select in it displaying the list of users.  In this situation the username or id won't mean much to the user so I need to show firstname lastname.

I've tried:

```
<form:select id="userSelect" name="userId" path="user.id">
    <option value="">Select to Edit</option>
    <form:options items="${user.userList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="lastname firstname" />
</form:select>
```

But that gives me a big error.  How can I make the itemLabels show lastname, firstname?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't think so. Either have a `getFullName()` getter in your object returning the concatenation of last and first names, or display the options one by one, in a loop:

```
<form:select id="userSelect" name="userId" path="user.id">
    <option value="">Select to Edit</option>
    <c:forEach var="theUser" items="${user.userList}">
        <form:option value="${theUser.id}"><c:out value="${theUser.lastname} ${theUser.firstname}"/></form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

With concatenation performed by `user.getFullName()`:

```
<form:select path="user"
   items="${user.userList}"
   itemValue="id"
   itemLabel="fullName">
</form:select>
```

Comment: Of course its so simple why didn't I think of that!  A getting in my object that returns the concatenated string.  I think it's time for bed if I'm missing that.

Comment: Not the most elegant way in my opinion. Try using spring Formatter. It provides an easy way of "transforming" your objects from strings in a form to a concrete object

Comment: @sashok_bg I'd love to see an example of what you're referring to.  Please, show me how to use "spring Formatter" to do this, that'd be awesome!

Comment: @kasdega You can take a look at the official doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html , or check out my test project repo on git hub https://github.com/sashokbg/schedule/tree/master/src/main/java/bg/alexander

Comment: I'm able to display all values in the drop down now but how do I capture the selected drop down value in my spring controller?